# How to get bounding boxes for each character in a String drawn to a bitmap image?

Tags: swift, tesseract, bounding-box

I'm rendering arbitrary text strings in various fonts to TIFF files for training `tesseract`.  I need to generate a "box file" which specifies the coordinates for the bounding rectangles for each character in the string (as rendered to the image).

The target is MacOS, not IOS.

[NSFont's getBoundingRects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/2887175-getboundingrects) will return the bounding rectangles for a list of glyphs:

```
func getBoundingRects(NSRectArray, forCGGlyphs: UnsafePointer<CGGlyph>, count: Int)
```

But how do I get the glyphs from either the string or rendered image?

Here's the relevant code:

```
private func makeImageFromString(inString : String) -> NSBitmapImageRep
{
    print("makeImageWithColor: \(inString). Font: \(mFontName)")

    // the docs say 'size' should be in points, but seems to be pixels
    let font = NSFont(name: mFontName, size: mTextHeightPixels)
    
    if (font == nil)
    {
        print("Font '\(mFontName) not found")
        exit(2)
    }
    
    let br = font!.boundingRectForFont
    print("boundingRect: \(br.width) x \(br.height)")
    
    let stringSize : CGSize = inString.size(withAttributes: [.font: font])
    
    // round width to nearest 10, plus padding
    let  adjWidth = Int(stringSize.width / 10) * 10 + TEXT_MARGIN_RIGHT
    let adjHeight = Int(stringSize.height / 10) * 10 + 2 * TEXT_MARGIN_BOTTOM
    
    print("stringSize: \(stringSize). adjWidth: \(adjWidth) adjHeight: \(adjHeight)")

    let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(
        bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
        pixelsWide: Int(adjWidth),
        pixelsHigh: Int(adjHeight),
        bitsPerSample: 8,
        samplesPerPixel: 4,
        hasAlpha: true,
        isPlanar: false,
        colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        bitsPerPixel: 0)
    
    let context = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: rep!)
    
    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    NSGraphicsContext.current = context
    
    let bkgndRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: adjWidth, height: adjHeight)
    
    let ctx = context?.cgContext
    
    ctx?.addRect(bkgndRect)
    
    ctx?.setFillColor(red: BKND_COLOR.redComponent, green: BKND_COLOR.greenComponent, blue: BKND_COLOR.blueComponent, alpha: 1)
    ctx?.fillPath()
    
    let textFontAttributes =
    [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font:            font,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: TEXT_COLOR,
    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    
    let loc = CGPoint(x: TEXT_MARGIN_LEFT, y: TEXT_MARGIN_BOTTOM) // text origin is lower left corner
    inString.draw(at: loc, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    
    let imgSize = CGSize(width: adjWidth, height: adjHeight)
    let image   = NSImage(size: imgSize)
    image.addRepresentation(rep!)
    
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
    
    return rep! // return rendered image
}
```